# Assert that variable is list of a given type

Tags: python, list, types, assert

How do I check if an argument passed to a function is a list of items of a given type?

For example, I'd like to check that `apples` is indeed a `list` of `Apple` objects, not of `Orange` or `Cockroach` objects.

```
class AppleJuiceMaker:
    def __init__(self, apples):
        assert isinstance(apples, list[Apple])  # <-- obviously doesn't work
        self._apples = list(apples)
```

I could loop through all the items in `apples` and check them one by one, but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: No, there is not. Lists by definition are collections of heterogenous objects. In any case, are you really sure you need to do this, rather than relying on duck typing?